# How to set CPU settings properly for slurm job?

Tags: slurm

I have a job that uses a moderate amount of the allocated memory, and all of the CPU.  How should I adjust the CPU settings, memory settings, or both?  The job info, and its slurm settings are below:

```
Wait time            : 00:00:15 
Reserved walltime    : 03:00:00 
Used walltime        : 00:00:55 
Used CPU walltime    : 00:00:55 
Used CPU time        : 00:00:51 
% User (computation) : 71.22% 
% System (I/O)       : 28.78% 
CPU efficiency       : 93.93% 
Reserved memory      : 80G 
Max memory used      : 45.83G (estimate) 
Memory efficiency    : 57.28% 
Max disk write       : 10.24K 
Max disk read        : 28.26M
```

settings in the slurm script:

```
#SBATCH --time=3:00:00  
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=80G
```

Obviously the CPU efficiency is extremely high (94%).  I'm not explicitly running any parallelism, so I'm not sure how to set the memory/CPU settings to prevent this OOM.  Thanks.